# Expected number of dice rolls require to make a sum greater than or equal to K?

Tags: self-study, mean, expected-value, dice, saddlepoint-approximation

A 6 sided die is rolled iteratively. What is the expected number of rolls required to make a sum greater than or equal to K?

Before Edit

```
P(Sum>=1 in exactly 1 roll)=1
P(Sum>=2 in exactly 1 roll)=5/6
P(Sum>=2 in exactly 2 rolls)=1/6
P(Sum>=3 in exactly 1 roll)=5/6
P(Sum>=3 in exactly 2 rolls)=2/6
P(Sum>=3 in exactly 3 rolls)=1/36
P(Sum>=4 in exactly 1 roll)=3/6
P(Sum>=4 in exactly 2 rolls)=3/6
P(Sum>=4 in exactly 3 rolls)=2/36
P(Sum>=4 in exactly 4 rolls)=1/216
```

After Edit

```
P(Sum>=1 in atleast 1 roll)=1
P(Sum>=2 in atleast 1 roll)=5/6
P(Sum>=2 in atleast 2 rolls)=1
P(Sum>=3 in atleast 1 roll)=4/6
P(Sum>=3 in atleast 2 rolls)=35/36
P(Sum>=3 in atleast 3 rolls)=1
P(Sum>=4 in atleast 1 roll)=3/6
P(Sum>=4 in atleast 2 rolls)=33/36
P(Sum>=4 in atleast 3 rolls)=212/216
P(Sum>=4 in atleast 4 rolls)=1
```

I am not sure this is correct first of all and but I think this probability is related to the expected number of rolls?

But I don't know how to proceed further. Am I proceeding in the right direction?

Comment: How did you get $P(S\geq 2 \text{ in 2 rolls})$?

Comment: @Glen_b You have to get a number less than 2 in the first roll which is 1. So probability of getting 1 is 1/6 and the second roll can be any number. if you get a number greater or equal to 2 in the first roll, then you wont go for a second roll.

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on. You don't describe that as "P(S\geq 2 in 2 rolls)"; that expression implies the number of rolls is fixed. What you want is either "P(exactly 2 rolls required to get $S\geq 2$)" or "P(at least 2 rolls required to get $S\geq 2$)".

Comment: @Glen_b Yeah thats the confusion. P(exactly 2 rolls required to get S>2) i guess. All i ultimately want to calculate is Expected number of rolls to reach a sum greater than K?

Comment: @Glen_b should I use atleast or exactly for this purpose? And how to calculate expected number of rolls for larger sum like 10000?

Comment: You may find the discussion in the hints for Q24 (see page 33) [here](http://www.madandmoonly.com/doctormatt/mathematics/dice1.pdf) of some help. (More generally, this is a special case of a first passage time problem.)

Comment: some related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738850/number-of-dice-rolls-taken-to-reach-a-certain-sum       http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104299/dice-problem-throws-necessary-for-sum-multiple-of-n           http://www.lucamoroni.it/the-dice-roll-sum-problem/

Answer (score 3):

This is so far only some ideas for another, more exact, approach, based on the same observation that my first answer. With time I will extend this ...

First, some notation. Let $K$ be some given, positive (large) integer. We want the distribution of $N$, which is the minimum number of throws of an ordinary dice to get sum at least $K$. So, first we define $X_i$ as the outcome of dice throw $i$, and $X^{(n)}=X_1+\dots+X_n$. If we can find the distribution of $X^{(n)}$ for all $n$ then we can find the distribution of $N$ by using
$$
   P(N \ge n)=  P(X_1+\dots+X_n \le K),
$$
and we are done.

Now, the possible values for $X_1+\dots+X_n$ are $n,n+1,n+2,\dots,6n$, and for $k$ in that range, to find the probability $P(X_1+\dots+X_n=k)$, we need to find the total number of ways to write $k$ as a sum of exactly $n$ integers, all in the range $1,2,\dots,6$. But that is called an restricted integer composition, a problem well studied in combinatorics.  Some related questions on math SE is found by  https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=integer+compositions

So searching and studying that combinatorics literature we can get quiet precise results. 
I will follow up on that, but later ...

Answer (score 2):

**There is a simple closed formula in terms of the roots of a degree-6 polynomial.**

It's actually a little easier to consider a general fair die with $d\ge 2$ faces labeled with the numbers $1,2,\ldots, d.$

Let $e_k$ be the expected number of rolls needed to equal or exceed $k.$  For $k\le 0,$ $e_k=0.$  Otherwise the expectation is one more than the expectation of the number of rolls to reach the immediately preceding value, which would be among $k-d, k-d+1, \ldots, k-1,$ whence

$$e_k = 1 + \frac{1}{d}\left(e_{k-d} + e_{k-d+1} + \cdots + e_{k-1}\right).\tag{1}$$

This *linear recurrence relation* has a solution in the form

$$e_k = \frac{2k}{d+1} + \sum_{i=1}^d a_i \lambda_i^k\tag{2}$$

where the $\lambda_i$ are the $d$ complex roots of the polynomial

$$T^d - \frac{1}{d}(T^{d-1} + T^{d-2} + \cdots + T + 1).\tag{3}$$

The constants $a_i$ are found by applying the solution $(2)$ to the values $k=-(d-1), -(d-2), \ldots, -1, 0$ where $e_k=0$ in every case.  This gives a set of $d$ linear equations in the $d$ constants and it has a unique solution.  That the solution works can be demonstrated by verifying the recurrence $(1)$ using the fact that every root satisfies $(3):$

$$\eqalign{
1 + \frac{1}{d}\sum_{j=1}^{d} e_{k-j}  &= 1 + \frac{1}{d}\sum_{j=1}^{d} \left(\frac{2(k-j)}{d+1} + \sum_{i=1}^d a_i \lambda_i^{k-j}\right) \\
&= \frac{2k}{d+1} + \sum_{i=1}^d a_i \lambda_i^{k-d}\left[\frac{1}{d}(1 + \lambda_i + \cdots + \lambda_i^{d-1})\right] \\
&= \frac{2k}{d+1} + \sum_{i=1}^d a_i \lambda_i^{k-d}\lambda_i^d \\
&= \frac{2k}{d+1} + \sum_{i=1}^d a_i \lambda_i^k = e_k.
}$$

**This closed form solution gives us good ways to approximate the answer as well as to evaluate it accurately.**  (For small to modest values of $k,$ direct application of the recurrence is an effective computational technique.)  For example, with $d=6$ we can readily compute

$$e_{1\,000\,000} = 285714.761905\ldots$$

For approximations, there will be a unique largest root $\lambda_{+}=1$ so eventually (for sufficiently large $k$) the term $\lambda_{+}^k$ will dominate the $d$ terms in $(2).$ The error will decrease *exponentially* according to the second smallest norm of the roots.  Continuing the example with $k=6,$ the coefficient of $\lambda_{+}$ is $a_{+}=0.4761905$ and the next-smallest norm is $0.7302500.$  (Incidentally, the other $a_i$ tend to be very close to $1$ in size.)  Thus we may approximate the previous value as

$$e_{1\,000\,000} \approx \frac{2\times 10^6}{6+1} + 0.4761905 = 285714.761905\ldots$$

with an error on the order of $0.7302500^{10^6} \approx 10^{-314\,368}.$

---

To demonstrate how practical this solution is, here is `R` code that returns a function to evaluate $e_k$ for any $k$ (within the scope of double precision floating point calculations) and not overly large $d$ (it will bog down once $d\gg 100$):

```
die <- function(d, mult=1, cnst=1, start=rep(0,d)) {
  # Create the companion matrix (its eigenvalues are the lambdas).
  X <- matrix(c(0,1,rep(0,d-1)),d,d+1)
  X[, d] <- mult/d
  lambda <- eigen(X[, 1:d], symmetric=FALSE, only.values=TRUE)$values

  # Find the coefficients that agree with the starting values.
  u <- 2*cnst/(d+1)
  a <- solve(t(outer(lambda, 1:d, `^`)), start - u*((1-d):0))

  # This function assumes the starting values are all real numbers.
  f <- Vectorize(function(i) Re(sum(a * lambda ^ (i+d))) + u*i)

  list(f=f, lambda=lambda, a=a, multiplier=mult, offset=cnst)
}
```

As an example of its use, here it calculates the expectations for $k=1,2,\ldots, 16:$

```
round(die(6)$f(1:10), 3)
```

> 1.000 1.167 1.361 1.588 1.853 2.161 2.522 2.775 3.043 3.324 3.613 3.906 4.197 4.476 4.760 5.046

The object it returns includes the roots $\lambda_i$ and their multipliers $a_i$ for further analysis.  The first component of the multipliers array is the useful coefficient $a_{+}.$

(If you're curious what the other parameters of `die` are for, execute `die(2, 2, 0, c(1,0))$f(1:10)` and see whether you recognize the output ;-).  This generalization assisted in developing and testing the function.)

Comment: +1. The function `die` gives an error for me: `object 'phi' not found`.

Comment: @COOL Thanks for checking.  A last-minute change of variable name (from `phi` to `a`) to match the text was the culprit.  I have fixed (and checked) it.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to get exact expected number of rolls in general, but for a K.

Let N be the event of of expected rolling to get sum=>K.

for K=1, E(N)=1

for K=2, $E(N)=(\frac{5}{6}+2*1)/(\frac{5}{6}+1)=\frac{17}{11}$

and so on.

It will be going difficult to get E(N) for large K.
for example,for K=20 you'll need to expect from (4 rolls,20 rolls)

Central Limit Theorem will be more benefitiary with some % confidence.
as we know occurrence is uniformly distributed, for large values of K.
$$K(Sum)~follows~N(3.5N,\frac{35N}{12})$$(Normal Distribution)

Now you need "N" to get Sum at least K....
we convert it in standard normal distribution.$$\frac{K-3.5N}{\sqrt{\frac{35N}{12}}}=Z_\alpha$$ where $\alpha=1-confidence$%
You can get Z values from "Standard Normal Tables" or [from here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html) for example $Z_{0.01}=2.31,Z_{0.001}=2.98$

You know K,Z(at any error) ........ then you can get N=E(N) at some confidence % by solving equation.

Comment: How you calculated those probabilities? How did you arrive at that E(N) equation?

Comment: @UsualSuspect P(Sum>=2 in 1 roll)=5/6( you know)
P(Sum>=2 in 2 rolls)=1(because you must get sum at least 2 from 2 rollings)

and for E(N).........its just a Expected mean

Comment: Sorry i dint mention. Its not atleast, exactly 2 rolls. I understood the E(N) equation now.

Comment: @UsualSuspect ohh! by the way if you need E(N) for any particular K, then I can make it :).

Comment: i need for k=20 and k=10000. Its better if you explain me rather than straightly giving answers.

Comment: and what do you mean by K follows N(3.5N,35N/12)?

Comment: For k=20 & k=10000 getting expected number to roll would rather difficult,

Comment: K follows N(3.5N,35N/12) it means K follows Normal distribution

Comment: Do you know how to use Central limit theorem, it will give you good answer.

Comment: Or a clever solution E(N)=K/3.5 for large K, as you know expected Value per roll is 3.5

Comment: will K/3.5 give better results than central limit theorem? Can it be done more accurately?

Comment: Its good for E(Sum=K)=E(N)*3.5... But for E(Sum=>K)... That E(N) would also be good to some extent. CLT is common method for such sum because for the rolling increase the sum follows Normal Distribution.

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 0):

I will give one method to find an approximate solution. First, let $X_i$ be the random variable, "result of throw $i$ with the dice" and let $N$ be the number of throws necessary to reach a sum at least $k$. Then we have that 
$$
  P(N \ge n) = P(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n \le k)
$$
so to find the distribution of $N$ we need to find the convolutions of the distributions of the $X_i$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$, for all $n$.  Those convolutions can be found numerically, but for large $n$ it might be much work, so we try instead to approximate the cumulative distribution function for the convolutions, using saddlepoint methods. For another example of saddlepoint methods, see my answer to [Generic sum of Gamma random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/general-sum-of-gamma-distributions/137318#137318)

We will use the Lugannini-Rice approximation for the discrete case, and follows R Butler: "Saddlepoint Approximations with Applications",  page 18 (second continuity correction).   First, we need the moment generating function of the $X_i$, which is
$$
M(T) = E e^{tX_i}= \frac16 (e^t+e^{2t}+e^{3t}+e^{4t}+e^{5t}+e^{6t})
$$
Then the cumulant generating function for the sum of $n$ independent dice becomes
$$K_n(t)=n \cdot log(\frac16\sum_{i=1}^6 e^{it})
$$
and we also need the first few derivatives of $K$, but we will find those symbolically using R. The code is the following:

```
 DD <- function(expr, name, order = 1) {
        if(order < 1) stop("'order' must be >= 1")
        if(order == 1) D(expr, name)
        else DD(D(expr, name), name, order - 1)
     }

make_cumgenfun  <-  function() {
    fun0  <-  function(n, t) n*log(mean(exp((1:6)*t)))
    fun1  <-  function(n, t) {}
    fun2  <-  function(n, t) {}
    fun3  <-  function(n, t) {}
    d1  <-  DD(expression(n*log((1/6)*(exp(t)+exp(2*t)+exp(3*t)+exp(4*t)+exp(5*t)+exp(6*t)))),  "t", 1)
    d2  <-  DD(expression(n*log((1/6)*(exp(t)+exp(2*t)+exp(3*t)+exp(4*t)+exp(5*t)+exp(6*t)))),  "t", 2)
    d3  <-  DD(expression(n*log((1/6)*(exp(t)+exp(2*t)+exp(3*t)+exp(4*t)+exp(5*t)+exp(6*t)))),  "t", 3)
    body(fun1)  <-  d1
    body(fun2)  <-  d2
    body(fun3)  <-  d3
    return(list(fun0,  fun1,  fun2,  fun3))
}
```

Next, we must solve the saddlepoint equation.

That is done by the following code:

```
funlist  <-  make_cumgenfun()

# To solve the saddlepoint equation for n,  k:
solve_speq  <-   function(n, k)  {# note that n+1 <= k <= 6n is needed
    Kd  <-  function(t) funlist[[2]](n, t)
    k  <-  k-0.5
    uniroot(function(s) Kd(s)-k,  lower=-100,  upper=1,  extendInt="upX")$root
}
```

Note that the above code is not very robust, for values of $k$ far in either tail of the distribution it will not work. Then some code for actually calculating the tail probability function, approximately, by the Luganini-Rice approximation, following Butler, page 18, (second continuity correction):

## Function for returning the tail probability:

#

```
Ghelp  <-  function(n, k) {
    stilde  <-  solve_speq(n, k)
    K  <-  function(t) funlist[[1]](n, t)
    Kd <-  function(t) funlist[[2]](n, t)
    Kdd <- function(t) funlist[[3]](n, t)
    Kddd <- function(t) funlist[[4]](n, t)
    w2tilde  <-  sign(stilde)*sqrt(2*(stilde*(k-0.5)-K(stilde)))  
    u2tilde  <-  2*sinh(stilde/2)*sqrt(Kdd(stilde))
    mu  <-  Kd(0)
    result  <- if (abs(mu-(k-0.5)) <= 0.001) 0.5-Kddd(0)/(6*sqrt(2*pi)*Kdd(0)^(3/2))  else
    1-pnorm(w2tilde)-dnorm(w2tilde)*(1/w2tilde - 1/u2tilde)
    return(result)
}
G  <- function(n, k) {
      fun  <- function(k) Ghelp(n, k)
      Vectorize(fun)(k)
  }
```

Then let us try to use this to calculate a table of the distribution, based on the formula
$$
  P(N \ge n) = P(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n \le k) \\
          = 1-P(X_1+\dots+X_n \ge k+1) \\
          = 1-G(n,k+1)
$$
where $G$ is the function fron the R code above.

Now, let us answer the original question with $K=20$. Then the minimum number of rolls is 4 and the maximum number of rolls is 20. The probability that 20 rolls is needed is very small, and can be calculated exactly from the binomial formula, I leave that to the reader. (the approximation above will not work for $n=20$).

So the probability that $N \ge 19$ is approximated by

```
> 1-G(20, 21)
[1] 2.220446e-16
```

The probability that $N\ge 10$ is approximated by:

```
> 1-G(10, 21)
[1] 0.002880649
```

And so on.  Using all this, you can get an approximation for the expectation yourself.  This should be much better than the approximations based on the central limit theorem.