# Stopping outcome on reaching/crossing a target

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, finite-population

I keep on throwing a fair die repeatedly till the cumulative sum reaches or crosses 100. What is the probability that the last throw was a six? This needs to be solved without asymptotic assumptions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might get some useful ideas from the closely related thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145621.

Comment: Whuber, thanks for your suggestion. So, it seems we cannot find a closed-form solution without assuming 100 to be a large number, right? That was where I got stuck, and posted this in the first place.

Comment: That thread shows just the opposite: it explains how you can compute the value exactly and shows why it will be very close to $2/7$.  Indeed, the answer is a rational number which, in reduced form, is a quotient of two 71-digit numbers and is about 4e-15 less than $2/7$.