# Probability of a sum of random variables falling in a given range

Tags: distributions, sum

Given a distribution $P$, two values $a$ and $b$, $x=0$, and the following process:

1. Draw a number $r$ from $P$ and add it to $x$, this is $x = x+r$.
2. Keep doing this until $x$ is higher than $a$.
3. Check if the final value of $x$ falls in the range $R=(a, b)$

Which is the probability of $x \in R$?

---

Phrasing this is a more mathematical way. Define $n(a)$ as

$n(a) = \min \{ n  | r_1 + r_2 + ... + r_n > t  \}$

where $r_i \sim P$. Then define the sum $s(a)$.

$s(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n(a)} r_i$.

$n(a)$ is the stopping time (how many times are we going to draw values from $P$ before stopping), and $s(a)$ is the value that we will have after the process.

Then the question is, which is $\mathbb{P}(s(a) \leq b)$?

---

For more clarity, here you have two examples of the process. Each jump represents the addition of a random value $r \sim P$ to $x$. In this example, the final value falls in the range $(a, b)$.

[image: x falls in (a, b)]

But in this example, the final value of $x$ falls out of the range $(a, b)$.
[image]

Notice that

- $b$ is not used to generate the value $x$. It's only used to check if the final value $x$ falls in the range $(a, b)$.
- The bigger the value of $b$ the higher the probability of $x \in (a, b)$. In fact, if $b=\infty$ then we have a probability of $1$.
- We can use any distribution $P$, but maybe there are distributions where the process never ends. For example, if the distribution has a domain in the negative reals and $a > 0$ the process will never end.

Comment: Yes it plays a role, if $b=a$ then the probability is 0, but if $b=\infty$ then the probability is 1.

Comment: Then you need to revise your description, which must be incomplete!

Comment: Why? I don't understand why it's not clear in the original description. The idea is to add up numbers until you get a number higher than $a$ but without wanting to get a value higher than $b$.

Comment: That last part *ut without wanting to get a value higher than *  is nowwhere in your Q! Please read it again, and edit ...

Comment: Is $P$ the uniform distribution on $(a,b)$ ?

Comment: @StratosFair no, it is any distribution.

Comment: alexm, I believe I see what you're trying to ask.  There's potential for confusion, though, because you use $b$ in a context where it's unneeded.  The process stops when $x\ge a,$ *period,* regardless of what $b$ might be.  However, *after the process has stopped,* you check whether $x\le b.$  I think if you were to clear that up in your post (assuming this is a correct interpretation), it would quickly be reopened.  You also need to specify that $P$ won't produce many negative numbers (having a positive expected value would suffice), for otherwise the process might never stop!

Comment: @Glen_b thank you for your feedback. I've just edited the question with some examples and a more formal definition of the problem. Let me know if now it's clear :)

Comment: Although after the edit I have voted to reopen this question, it has a fundamental problem: the answer, and how one goes about getting an answer, depends on the details of the distribution $P.$  What can you tell us about this distribution in the situation you actually face?

Comment: I would like to keep the answer as general as possible. I don't want to fix the details of $P$, but have an answer that depends on $P$, $a$, and $b$. Does it make sense?

Comment: That's a little too broad for our format.  This is a difficult area of probability theory: you describe a form of random walk with an absorbing barrier at $a.$  A great deal has been written about just the cases where $P$ is a binomial distribution or is a Normal distribution.  What you ask, then, looks like it would be an extensive treatise.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145621 is an example of just one very special case of this situation.